# MS-VS2008 Keyboard mapping problem

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, hotkeys

I am trying to set my own hotkey combination for the action **Edit.FindNext** in visualstudio 2008 under:

**Tools.Customize -> Keyboard**

but these simply dont take effect, so as soon as i close the dialog my VS keeps working with the default combination: **Ctrl + F3**, and the one i set is just ignored, although its still set in the configuration.

restart didnt help.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting a hotkey in VS can be tricky. Be aware of the following: The same hotkey can be used for different things, depending on the context.
For example, it is possible, that you defined the hotkey for "Global", but for "Text Editor" your default hotkey is still registered and the new one might even be registered for something else in the context of "Text Editor". So when you enter your new hotkey, check out the Combobox "Shortcut currently used by", maybe it will show you what the problem is.

Comment: @Danile thank you i found the problem, as this was an issue of the global context i will accept your anser and post my own for the detailed information regarding the microsoft statements (read my post for details).

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem,

i tried to set the Ctrl + Left Arrow for the find next action but the Left-Arrow can not be used in global as [microsoft states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5zwses53%28v=VS.90%29.aspx):

> The following keys cannot be assigned
> to a command in Global: PRINT SCRN/SYS
> RQ, SCROLL LOCK, PAUSE/BREAK, TAB,
> CAPS LOCK, INSERT, HOME, END, PAGE UP,
> PAGE DOWN, Windows logo keys,
> Application key, any of the ARROW
> keys, or ENTER; NUM LOCK, DEL, or
> CLEAR on the numeric keypad; or
> CTRL+ALT+DELETE.

so i had to set this to the texteditor context, and it worked.